# Record my camera (and voice) and my screen side by side

Tags: skype, macros, video-recording

I am using Mac.

I would like to record a video, where I am shooting by Mac's embedded camera on the left, and my screen is on the right. On the same time, my voice should be recorded.

Does anyone know which software is good for that?

Comment: I think that people usually accomplish this by recording each video separately, then combining them.

Comment: Really? That's not convenient, we meed to make sure the synchronisation...